# NFS server inaccessible on worker node

Tags: docker, kubernetes, networking, nfs

Summary : My NFS server pod is not accessible if deployed on the worker node.

### Context

I have an issue with my Kubernetes cluster. It's composed of 2 nodes. One node is the control-plane & master, the other is just a worker.

What I'm trying to do is configure an NFS server on the worker node. I want the server to be accessible from both nodes. I used an existing image to configure my deployment :

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-service
spec:
  selector:
    role: nfs
  clusterIP: 10.100.171.36
  ports:
    - name: nfs
      port: 2049
      protocol: UDP
    - name: rpcbind
      port: 111
      protocol: UDP
    - name: nfs-tcp
      port: 2049
      protocol: TCP
    - name: rpcbind-tcp
      port: 111
      protocol: TCP
---
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-server-pod
  labels:
    role: nfs
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    role: master
  containers:
    - name: nfs-server-container
      image: cpuguy83/nfs-server
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      args:
        - /exports
```

I don't have any problem when deploying this pod. After that, I want to deploy other pods and mounting a volume which uses this NFS server. One of these pods is a docker registry, deployed like that :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docker-registry-pod
  labels:
    app: registry
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    role: master
  containers:
  - name: registry
    image: registry:latest
    volumeMounts:
    - name: registry-pv
      mountPath: "/var/lib/registry"
    - name: auth-vol
      mountPath: "/auth"
      readOnly: true
    env:
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH
      value: "htpasswd"
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM
      value: "Registry Realm"
    - name: REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH
      value: "/auth/htpasswd"
    - name: REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED
      value: "true"
  volumes:
  - name: auth-vol
    secret:
      secretName: auth-secret
  - name: registry-pv
    nfs:
      server: 10.100.171.36
      path: /registry
```

### Problem

If the NFS server node is deployed on the master node, everything is fine. The volume is mounted correctly in the docker-registry pod, regardless of whether the registry pod is located on the master or the worker.
However, if I deploy the NFS server pod on the worker node (which is what I want), then the docker-registry pod fails to mount the volume. Event if the docker-registry pod is also on the worker node. The deployment is stuck with the status "ContainerCreating" and after few seconds, the only logs available are :

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age    From               Message
  ----     ------       ----   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    2m13s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/docker-registry-pod to master-node
  Warning  FailedMount  10s    kubelet            Unable to attach or mount volumes: unmounted volumes=[registry-pv], unattached volumes=[kube-api-access-skbnf registry-pv auth-vol]: timed out waiting for the condition
  Warning  FailedMount  8s     kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "registry-pv" : mount failed: exit status 32
Mounting command: mount
Mounting arguments: -t nfs 10.100.171.36:/registry /var/lib/kubelet/pods/b73f297c-1fb1-42de-ab14-cdbbe974103a/volumes/kubernetes.io~nfs/registry-pv
Output: mount.nfs: Connection timed out
```

Because it's a timeout error, I'm guessing it can't reach the server. However, I can't find any useful logs that could help find the root of the problem.

Do you have any idea that could help me with this problem?

Thank you for your help.

### Additional information

- My nodes run under Debian 10 and the package `nfs-common` is correctly installed on both nodes
- Both nodes run the Kubernetes version 1.22.0 and have been deployed with kubeadm
- My firewall is inactive on the worker node.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be anyhow related to network. I was trying to reproduce your example and I wasn't even able to get this work on control-plane node while you could. I switched `nfs` image cause that one didn't work properly for me. As for networks, I deployed two pods with `nginx` image (can be `ubuntu`), installed `telnet` and tested connectivity to the pod/service from both nodes - works just fine. If I find anything, I'll get back (there are different questions, but all of them are about `nfs-common` package which you've already installed).

Comment: @moonkotte First, thank you for your help. As you said, the network doesn't seem to be the issue. My nodes can communicate, and I don't have any problem with the other pods.

Comment: By any chance, can you please try to remove both containers from master node, restart node and try again? The closest I got is to have it work once until restart, but on any hosts configuration. I switched to `erichough/nfs-server` image and it finally showed error `kernel module nfs is missing -> ERROR: nfs module is not loaded in the Docker host's kernel (try: modprobe nfs)` while it's of course loaded...

Comment: @moonkotte I tried but unfortunately, it still doesn't work. I finally set up a workaround that is enough for my use case. Thank you for your time and your help.